# Is it possible to choose launcher activity at run-time?

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity

Is it possible to have multiple launcher activities and decide at which activity is launched at run-time in android? I would like to display a sign-in activity if the user is not already logged in and the home page activity if the user is already logged in. I am using Firebase Auth for authentication.